# Insert a "%" between each character in a vector for R

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
vec = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-02", "2019-03-03")
```

I am looking to create a string for an API call that takes the vector, removes the spaces and adds a % between each character

```
vec = "2019-01-01%2019-02-02%2019-03-03"
```

How do i create a vector that automatically inserts the "%" and removes the spaces?

I have tried the following without success. Thank you

```
paste0(vec, sep = "%")
```

Comment: There is no `sep` argument in `paste0`. Use `collapse` : `paste0(vec, collapse = "%")`

Comment: thanks Ronak. Can you put answer so i can give you credit

Comment: Thank you but actually this has been asked and answered previously so I marked it as duplicate of that post.